# Direct calculation gives other result in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, variables

I'm having a weird thing going on in matlab. I tried to calculate the following simple line:

```
>> -0.5800^3+2*(-0.5800^2)+70*-0.5800+40

ans =

   -1.4679
```

However, the result differs when I calculate it with an assigned variable (a):

```
>> a = -0.5800;
>> c = a^3+2*(a^2)+70*a+40

c =

   -0.1223
```

I overlooked it many times to make sure I did not made a stupid mistake. Am I missing something MATLAB does different in these situations (calculations with variables)? My calculator gives the upper result. Thanks in advance for the clarification!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  -0.5800^3+2*(-0.5800^2)+70*-0.5800+40
= -(0.5800^3)+2*(-(0.5800^2))+70*-0.5800+40
= -1.4679
```

but with a variable it is read as:

```
  (-0.5800)^3+2*((-0.5800)^2)+70*-0.5800+40
= -0.1223
```

Watch your parentheses and operator precedence.

Answer (score 3):

Hi the problem is due to

```
(-0.5800^2)
```

which is calculated as

```
-(0.5800^2)
```